# Fall back from a core file

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, core

is it possible to use magento core files as fallback?

Example: I really need to make a change in this file:

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`

It will work if I create a copy at

`app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php ?`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Copying the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php` file to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php` should work. In Magento, there are 2 directories where controllers are placed; one is `controllers` and the other one is `Controller` (note the upper case and the singular).

The `controllers` (note the small case and plural) directory is used intentionally to prevent the classes inside this directory from being autoloaded.

Magento's autoloader will always capitalise the first letter after underscore and it'll expect such a directory to exist. In this case, whenever a class `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` is used, Magento will try to autoload the same by splitting the class name using underscore (_).

Hence this should work as expected. However if you try to use the same logic to override a controller from the `controllers` (note the small case and plural) directory, it will not work and you need to create a module to override it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override controllers, you will need to make a module if you want your code to stay persistent when updates/patches are made.